# cURL error 77 with Laravel 5 and XAMPP under Windows

Tags: php, curl, laravel-5

I use Mailgun within my application. During testing, I got this error

```
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

No problem, I had this error before on my Laptop. Following [this instructions](https://codeontrack.com/solve-laravelxamppguzzlehttp-curl-error-60-no-sll-certificate/) I solved this error. After this, everything worked fine on my laptop. But on my desktop-pc, I get this error:

```
cURL error 77: error setting certificate verify locations:
CAfile: ‪C:\Users\Fabian\webserver\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem
CApath: none (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

The file cacert.pem is in this directory. In my PHP.ini I added the following line:

```
curl.cainfo = "‪C:\Users\Fabian\webserver\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
```

The directory C:\Users\Fabian\webserver contains the xampp files (changed xampp to webserver during installation).

The curls-website says this about error 77:

> Problem with reading the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Windows 10 and Xampp) it was an access rights issue.
I solved it simply putting cacert.pem outside of Xampp folder.

I just added this to my php.ini:
curl.cainfo="C:\cacert\cacert.pem"